# How to connect to a Cisco VPN in "native mode"?

Tags: ubuntu, vpn, cisco, cisco-vpn, networkmanager

I need to connect to a VPN, but I am not an expert on the subject at all, so if anyone can help me, I would appreciate it.

I was given the following data, telling me that this info is for a "Cisco config in native mode". I am going to paste literally the words in the email:

- **Dedicated public IP**: it shows an IP which ends on 9. I don't really know what is this for...
- **Remote**: it shows a domain name. If I check out its IP, I get the same IP as the one written in "Dedicated public IP", but ending on 1. Is this the gateway?.
- **PSK**: OK, it shows a pre-shared key, but I don't have field to write it in.
- **Group name**: the group name.
- **User**: an username.
- **Password**: the username's password.

I am using Kubuntu. With this data, someone who knows about this, which VPN should you choose in the network manager?

If I select **Cisco AnyConnect Compatible VPN (openconnect)**, I can fill in **Gateway**, **CA Certificate**, **Proxy**, **User Certificate**, **Private Key**... but no PSK, no group, no user, no password.

If I select **Cisco Compatible VPN (vpnc)**, I can fill in **Gateway**, **User name**, **User password**, **Group name**, **Group password** (I was not given this)... Almost, but no PSK.

The left VPN types ask for other pretty different fields.

The only VPN type I find which gives me the chance to fill in a PSK is the **Layer 2 Tunneling Protocol (L2TP)**, in its advanced settings, but I can't specify other data, like the group.

Can anyone give me a clue on how to do?

Comment: ask the vendor which provided you the information?

Comment: @djdomi that is the option, I was asking here just in case the solution was obvious for any of you, since I am a newbie on this subject.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, finally I got the solution:

- The VPN was **vpnc** type.
- As I thought, the data called *Dedicated public IP* was useless.
- The domain name called *Remote* was finally the **Gateway**.
- And the *PSK* was the password of the group. It would be easier for me if he just wrote me *Group password*...

I do not know if this would be helpful for someone, but I leave the answer here, just in case.

Comment: but remind, to accept this answer in 24 hours @forvas or we will be reminded until the end of this portal on this question to accept an answer

Comment: I'll set it as the correct one as soon as Server Fault leaves me to do it (after 24 hours).